# Update array of objects leads to blank array

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

Please tell me what I'm missing here. When I update the Array of objects my collection updates with an empty array. I'm using [meteor-collection2-core](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core) and [node-simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema).

Path: `Method`

```
testArray = [{
    "institution": "Swinburn",
    "uniqueId": 1501036480813,
    "qualification": "Bachelor of Commerce",
    "completed": "2017"
}]

ProfileCandidate.update('Ntzj6kE8qZsvSPMEP', {$set: {educationQualifications: testArray}});
```

Path: `Collection`

```
export const ProfileCandidate = new Mongo.Collection('profileCandidate');

const ProfileCandidateSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
  },
  educationQualifications: { type: Array, optional: true },
  'educationQualifications.$': { type: Object, optional: true },
  'educationQualifications.$.uniqueId': { type: Number, optional: true },
  'educationQualifications.$.institution': { type: String, optional: true },
  'educationQualifications.$.qualification': { type: String, optional: true },
  'educationQualifications.$.completed': { type: String, optional: true }
});

ProfileCandidate.attachSchema(ProfileCandidateSchema);
```

Comment: Does your method throw any errors on the client side callback?

Comment: No errors becuase it has technically work. It updates with an empty array.

Comment: What does it throw, when you remove the optional:true attributes on the Objects related fields? (And then further on all optional fields?) Does it throw anything at all? This may bring you a bit further.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Sorry for the time delay. Removing option:true on Objects related fields doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Okay that shows, that there is no problem with your schema or such. Maybe it is a mongo problem. You may try an approach using `$push` combined with `$in` or `$addToSet` if this does not work either, please post a minimal prototype here or on fiddle or github, so that we can reproduce. I am also interested in this errors, since it seems to be rather mongo related.

Answer (score 0):

In your method, try this:

```
ProfileCandidate.update({userId: 'Ntzj6kE8qZsvSPMEP'}, {$set: {educationQualifications: testArray}});
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. I get the same problem an empty array.